# Show post if in category

Tags: posts, loop, categories

I've searched a lot for options like has_category, in_category, get_the_category, but I couldn't make them work

Here's my pastebin

http://pastebin.com/Zi7auvtv

I want this code to run only if the post belongs to the category "destaque"

I didn't put my tries on the pastebin code to avoid being confusing

Some of my tries:

```
    if (in_category('destaque')) {
    echo 'The content';
    }

    OR

    if (has_category('destaque')) {
    echo 'The content';
    }

But nothing work
```

And so on, tried a lot more complex too, but no luck

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So this fails even when you know the post has the category for sure? Then something is messing up `$post` global for you, outside of the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try `in_category` again, but also with specifying the post id:

```
 if (in_category('destaque', $post->ID)) {

     //do whatever you need to

 }
```

Comment: Been there, didn't work

Comment: To clarify, 'destaque' is a term in the default categories and not a term in a custom taxonomy?